# What is the metamask algorithm for creating accounts based on one seed phrase?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, metamask, evm, ethereumjs

Metamask uses one seed phrase to generate other accounts. Thus, with one seed phrase you can restore all accounts. *But what is the algorithm for this?*

I want a script that could show 10 of my accounts from metamask using one seed phrase. I want to see the address and seed phrase of each account.

Answer (score 1):

It's done like this:

```js
import hdkey from 'ethereumjs-wallet/src/hdkey';
import * as bip39 from 'bip39'

const seedPhrase = process.env.SEED_PHRASE;
const walletsCount = 4;

const masterKey = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(await bip39.mnemonicToSeed(seedPhrase));

for (let i = 0; i < walletsCount; i++) {
  const wallet = masterKey.derivePath(`m/44'/60'/0'/0/${i}`).getWallet();
  const address = `0x${wallet.getAddress().toString('hex')}`;
  const privateKey = `0x${wallet.getPrivateKey().toString('hex')}`;

  console.log(`Address #${i}: ${address}`);
  console.log(`PrivateKey #${i}: ${privateKey}`);
}
```

Where "m/44'/60'/0'/0/" is BIP44.